# Reach a variable from another class (which is controller class of JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to implement a game on `JavaFX`. Moreover, I'm dealing with an `FXML` file so I have a `main` class and `controller` class. My question is how can I reach the objects of the `main` class from the `controller` class. To be more clear I will share a simple code.

This is main class:

```
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Risk3.fxml"));

        // Main Pane
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(root);

        // Main scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

So for example I want to reach `root` or `borderPane` from `controller` class which is:

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Should I make `root` and `borderPane` global and static or is there any another way to reach them ?.

Comment: why you are wrapping the panel loaded from the controller in a BorderPanel ?

Comment: actually i will add text fields around the map. also i will add a player menu to bottom. thats why i selected border pane and wrapped the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` panel can simply reached from the `FXML` controller using

`@FXML` tag like any component.

```
<BorderPane  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:id="root">
    ...
</BorderPane>
```